# numerical integration of integrals in the p-adaptive version of the finite element method

Tags: finite-element, quadrature, adaptive-mesh-refinement

In the *p-adaptive* version of the *finite element method*, elements are allowed to have shape functions with arbitrary different polynomial orders. Therefore regarding a 2D problem with quadrilateral hierarchic shape functions, the polynomial orders of four edge-modes of an element, $p_e^1,p_e^2,p_e^3,p_e^4$, and its internal-mode, $p_i$, might be in general not the same.

In such a case, what degree of *Gauss-Legendre* quadrature should be used to numerically integrate the area integrals on an element? My guess is that $\mathrm{max}(p_e^1,p_e^2,p_e^3,p_e^4,p_i)$ determines what accuracy order of quadrature to use.

Comment: Hey, @Masa here we have some discussion on the integration of finite elements in the context of high-order approximation. 
http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/integration.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a typical choice is to use the maximum -- which happens to be based on the polynomial degree of the finite element used for the element (notwithstanding the fact that some of its degrees of freedom might be constrained to enforce continuity with neighbors).